# laravel destroy just deletes last added stuff

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am a Laravel newbie. While writing and testing my code, I noticed that my destroy method isn't working right anymore and I cannot find the mistake I've made. So I hope you can help me out.

Whats my (software) target? I want to manage "projects". Every project has many reports. So I got a page with all created projects and I got a page with all reports listed in a table with buttons for "modify" and "delete". I finished all the CRUD stuff for projects and reports, when I recognized that, if I am hover over the delete-button of a report or project, the right ID of the chosen report or project is shown. If I am hitting the delete-button a dialog plopps up and a message is shown: "Do you really want to delete..." with "yes" and "no" buttons. So if I am pressing the "yes"-button Laravel is going to delete the last added database entry.

Even the projects as the reports too got their own controller. But both are using the same _messages.php. I think, that my mistake is in that file.

Excerpt from _messages.php:

```
@if(Session::has('sweet_alert.confirmDeleteReport'))
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <strong>Achtung!</strong> {{Session::get('sweet_alert.confirmDeleteReport')}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-8">
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ route('reports.destroy', $report->id) }}" title="Löschen" data-token="{{csrf_token()}}" data-method="delete">Löschen</a>
            <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="alert">Abbrechen</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

Excerpt from reportcontroller.php:

```
public function destroy(Report $report)
{
    $report->delete();
    Session::flash('sweet_alert.success','Der Bericht vom ' . $report->date . ' mit der Berichtsnummer ' . $report->reportNumber . ' wurde erfolgreich gelöscht.');
    return redirect()->route('reports.index');
}

public function delete(Report $report) {
    Session::flash('sweet_alert.confirmDeleteReport', 'Soll der Bericht vom ' . $report->date . ' mit der Berichtsnummer ' . $report->reportNumber . ' wirklich gelöscht werden? Dieser Vorgang kann nicht rückgängig gemacht werden.');
    return redirect()->route('reports.index');
}
```

Might there be the fault within the session? I flushed the cache by executing *php artisan config:cache* but with no luck. Every idea is welcome.

Greetings

Comment: Can you show your route ? And why do you have a delete function declared by you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have a page which lists all reports.  Each report has a delete button, and that button route maps to the `delete()` method you include above.  That method flashes a msg to the session, and reloads your report index.

Now on your report index, all reports are listed again, probably inside something like `@foreach ($reports as $report)`.  At the bottom of the page, you have the extract you have shown.  This uses `$report->id`, which on this page, after looping through all `$reports`, is just the last report in that collection.  So all it will do is delete the last report.

There are a few solutions I can see:

1) Flash the id of the report you want to delete along with your message in the `delete()` method. I am not familiar with sweet_alert but can you flash an array, your msg *and* the id?  Something like:

```
Session::flash('sweet_alert.confirmDeleteReport', [
    'id' => $report->id,
    'message' => 'Soll der Bericht ...'
]);
```

And then of course use *that* id in your alert:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ route('reports.destroy', Session::get('sweet_alert.confirmDeleteReport.id')) }}" ... </a>
```

Maybe the syntax is wrong, but I am assuming flashing an array is possible.

2) The way I usually do this kind of thing is use Javascript to populate the alert/modal/whatever with the required data when you click the delete button in the table.  Eg your delete buttons (in the main table/list) could have a data-id attribute:

```
<a href="#" data-id="{{ $report->id }}" class="btn btn-danger delete">Delete</a>
```

And some Javascript (pseudo code, implementation depends on how you have things set up):

```
$('a.delete').on('click', function(e) {

    // Prevent the default behaviour of clicking a link 
    e.preventDefault();

    // Find the id of the report clicked
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    // Update the href of the alert button so it will delete *that* report
    $('div.alert a.danger').attr('href', 'reports/' + id);

    // ... code to display the alert/modal
});
```

This way you avoid the page reload to get to your alert/modal.  Note this makes your `delete()` method obsolete, it would not be used any more.

**UPDATE**

If you need to pass some variable from your view/controller to your external JS file, you can do something like this:

**In the view**

```
<script>
    var url = "{{ route('reports.destroy', Session::get('sweet_alert.confirmDeleteReport.id')) }}";
</script>
```

**In your external JS** (must be loaded after the above inline script)

```
$('div.alert a.danger').attr('href', url);
```

Comment: Maybe before calling _messages.php he can pluck the id column from the reports table. Than after he put those in an array like $reports he can compact it and pass it to the view. This way when he is using the foreach($reports as $report) he can call $report->id inside the href attribute.

Comment: @JoanPlepi Yes, that's another good option - actually he already has the `$report` in that method so `return redirect()->route('reports.index')->with('deleteID', $report->id);` would work.

Comment: Hey guys. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hey guys. Thank you so much for your help. So I went on and found the solution which is @Don't Panic's advice #2. But since Laravel 5.4 (maybe earlier) you are not able to set javascript inline of an php file, did I understand that right? So I changed the app.js and added some code for my modal stuff. My old delete method is obsolete since now. But I think, that using my javascript code only in app.js is not that clean, isn't it? I wonder how if there is some best practice? So my new target would be to put all my message stuf into the controller destroy function and call the app.js with swal.

Comment: @SirHC you can use JS in your blade views, though I think better practice is to have it in external JS files.  I sometimes set some JS variables in inline `<script>` in the view, eg to get some Laravel route or something, then you can use that variable in your code in app.js.

Comment: Thanks again @Don'tPanic. Great help! So can I put some vars in my Session::flash and catch them with my js in app.js? So that I have everything central? As you said: I don't want to have any inline js in my blade-files. =)

Comment: I added your idea with the script in my view. But if I am doing that the console says: - Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed. What are I am doing wrong? I want to write my messages for the user ("Do you really want to delete?") in my controller into the sessions, as your example with the array. Then I want just one script with sweet alert, in which I place the passed vars (delete message text) from the controller.

Comment: @SirHC I have never heard or seen of the error you quote.  Googling it suggests it comes from Vuejs?  I am not familiar with Vuejs, and the current question/answer haven't dealt with it.  The `<script>` tag I suggested will work fine in a blade template.